# Vue Keep-Alive - Component won't stay alive during route changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, keep-alive

I defined the main page of my vue app to look like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <keep-alive>
      <app-header></app-header>
    </keep-alive>
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>

<script>
import appHeader from '../components/Header';

export default {
  components: {
    appHeader
  }
/* etc... */
}
```

My app UI is basically this Dashboard, with many different routes and sub-routes paths to show many pages, but in all pages (components) I want to show the app-header at the top of the page.

The problem is that I noticed recently, with every button clicked (that changes vue-router's route to another page), the app-header gets recreated (the created() lifecycle hook function is called)

I really don't understand why, since I added keep-alive, shouldn't it be rendered once?

Please help me figure this out, I am stuck, I literally researched the entire internet about it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Help please, I really can't figure this one out :(

Answer (score 1):

The `keep-alive` will work only in the section which is wrapped by the `<keep-alive>` tag. Here, only the `app-header` component will keep alive. If you need to apply this to all the components within the routes, you have to put the `<router-view>` inside `<keep-alive>`.

> Eg:

```
  <keep-alive>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </keep-alive>
```

Now the keep-alive will work for all the routes.

Comment: That's the point, I don't want the routes to be kept alive, I want ONLY the app header to be kept alive. The problem is that currently, the app header is calling the "created" lifecycle hook method everytime I change route, I check that by console.log..

I want it to be created once, and not re-render, even when I change routes

Comment: Then, there's a chance for this to happen if your parent component itself is included in the routing. It is not possible to say more without seeing your component structure and routing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I create the VueRouter object, I put inside it routes (array of objects), one of the main routes there is '/dashboard', and its pointing to that component which I posted. Before that is only the App.vue component, which contains a <router-view :key="$route.path"></router-view> wrapped by a <v-app></v-app>.

So, what do you mean by "if the parent component itself is included"?

The '/dashboard' route has many children routes that route to different places in the app, and when I navigate there and change route between the children, it re-renders.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from [Rijosh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60739624) is applicable only for Vue 2 and its router (Router v3.x). If someone uses Vue 3 (and Router v4.x), then code for `<keep-alive>` and `<router-view>` looks like this:

```
<router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
   <keep-alive>
      <component :is="Component" />
   </keep-alive>
</router-view>
```

More can be found in documentation [here](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/#router-view-keep-alive-and-transition).